# How to query multiple tables which are related by a column in another table using Django class based view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I created these models which are related by a common column [band_id] as shown in the code below;

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Date')
    band = models.ForeignKey(ModelC, related_name='band',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    
class ModelB(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    band = models.ForeignKey(ModelC, related_name='bandspends',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    spending = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class ModelC(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How do I query ModelA and ModelB such that I retrieve values from ModelA[date, band_id] and ModelB[band_id, spending] where band_id in ModelA = band_id in ModelB?

I have already written my view.py like the one below but the problem is that I cannot do this on a QuerySet.

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Oas_Spend.objects.select_related('band').filter(band_id=F('ModelC__brand_id')).values(
            'ModelC__band_id', 'ModelC__label',  'spending').join(
                ModelA.objects.select_related('band').filter('band__brand_id')).values('id', 'date')
        return queryset

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        # Serialize the data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        pagination_class = DataPagination

        # Return the serialized data in the response
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I expect to have a json like;

```
[
    {
        "band_id": 100,
        "band_label": "MLTR",
        "spending": 900.000,
        "id": 2212121,
        "date": "2018-02-01T00:00:00Z",

    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I could have access to both table through their common Foreign key using annotate() and calling the related name which was used to decorate the ForeignKey Field. Sample solution could be;

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        band_ids = Band.objects.values_list('band_id', flat=True)
        queryset = ModelA.objects.filter(id__in=band_ids).annotate(
            band=F('ModelC__bandspends__band'),
            spending=F('ModelC__bandspends__spending')
        )  
        return queryset
```

My Serializer.py looks like so;

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    band = serializers.CharField()
    spending = serializers.FloatField()
    date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ('band', 'spending', 'date')
```